# Is there a YUI 2.x equivalent to jQuery's scrollTo?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, yui

I want to create an animation to scroll the page smoothly when clicking on anchor links, just like jQuery.ScrollTo plugin (http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) does it.

I tried making it using YUI 2.x Animation utility, by animating the value of the property `document.activeElement.scrollTop`. It works on webkit only :'( - on the other browser, nothing happens - not even an error is raised.

```
goToAnchor = function(e, id) {
    var targetToGo = Dom.get(id),
        scrollToTarget = new Animation(document.activeElement,
            {
                scrollTop:
                {
                    from: document.activeElement.scrollTop,
                    to: targetToGo.offsetTop
                }
            },  1,  Easing.easeOut
        )
    Event.preventDefault(e);

    scrollToTarget.animate();
}
```

What I'd like to know is if there's a plugin that does this for YUI 2.x or how to do a cross browser compatible code to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that depending on browser you might need to scroll the `html` or the `body` element.

(*practially, you need to scroll both to be sure*)

Also at http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/animation/#scroll i see

```
var element = document.getElementById('test');
var myAnim = new YAHOO.util.Scroll(element, {
    scroll: {    
        to: [ 500, test.scrollTop ]
    } 
});
myAnim.animate();
```

Maybe that is what you are looking for (*still you will have to animate both `html` and `body`*)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
(function() {
  var scrollingBody = document.body;
  if (YAHOO.env.ua.gecko){
    scrollingBody = document.documentElement;
  }
  (new YAHOO.util.Scroll(
    scrollingBody,
    {
        scroll:
        {
            to: [0, 50]
        }
    },
    0.7,
    YAHOO.util.Easing.easeOut
)).animate();
})();
</script>
```